# Regularity of Daubechies wavelet

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, wavelets

I am reading the book Wavelets: Theory and applications by A. K. Louis, D. Maass, A. Rieder

(http://books.google.ca/books?id=58hpQgAACAAJ&dq=wavelets:+theory+and+application&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QF8JU6ONGILtoASz9YGAAg&ved=0CG0Q6AEwCQ)

In Section 2.2.4 and there is the following result about regularity of Daubechies wavelet:

There are constants $C^*, C>0$, such that
$$
|(\psi_m)^{\widehat{}}(x)|\leq C^{*}|x|^{-C\log m}.
$$

I am wondering how big these constants $C^{*}$ and $C$ could be?

Thank you